# Power BI embed visual using PowerBI Javascript library set focus mode

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are embedding a visual from a report using PowerBI-JavaScript library. 
Is there a way to set focus mode while embedding the visual.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no API to access In Focus mode.. however, you can use single visual embedding (https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Single-Visual) to get a similar experience.

Comment: We are using single visual embedding only but there is some extra space that comes around the Iframe. But if we manually click on on the set focus mode the visual takes up all the space

Comment: If you're referring to the gray shoulders around the visual, try adding `background: 1` to your `settings: ISettings` in your embed config.
This should take care of that issue.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358126/how-do-you-get-rid-of-the-grey-border-with-the-report-visuals-with-power-bi-embe for more details